# how to check the token bear in every request with keycloak and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, keycloak, bearer-token

I have created two microservices. The first microservice is responsible for communication with Keycloak, and the second microservice handles my application logic.

With each API call, a JWT token is sent along from Keycloak. The microservice will only respond if the token sent is a valid one.

I would like to know how to validate the access token in the second microservice. Could you please guide me on how to implement this validation process and provide some code examples using Spring Boot?